# Referencing R values in SQL blocks in RMarkdown

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown

I'm working with an SQL block in RMarkdown and know that I can reference R variables like:

````
```{sql connection=db}
select * from [dbo].[B] 
where BATCH_ID = ?BATCH_ID
```
````

Is there any special syntax that can be used to evaluate an R expression?  I'm hoping I can do something like:

````
```{sql connection=db}
select * from [dbo].[B] 
where BATCH_ID = ?RESULT$BATCH_ID
```
````

Is this possible?

Comment: If my reading of http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html#sql (under the  Using R Variables in Queries section) is correct, what you are proposing should work.  If it isn't you may want to do an intermediary assignment (`batch_id <- RESULT$BATCH_ID`) in an `r` chunk before the `sql` chunk and then use `BATCH_ID = ?batch_id`.  I don't use this version of knitr in my environment, so I can't test this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Found https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/ca04aa42ca59740408013dab7e6172af1c92f20d/R/engine.R and from line 429 onwards I can see the code for processing the variable substitutions.  It just looks for variables, no evaluation of expressions, but at least I know where to go now to add that if I want to.

In the short term, I added the following to mass-pollute my environment with the variables I needed (didn't want to be eeking them out one-by-one).

```
mapply(FUN=assign, names(RESULT), RESULT, MoreArgs=list(pos=1))
```